# Deploying Symfony Hello World on App Engine

Tags: php, symfony, google-app-engine

I'm following the official google tutorial '[How to Run Symfony Hello World on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/symfony-hello-world?hl=en)' on how to deploy https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/symfony-standard.git

I've setup the default cloud storage bucket but I haven't setup the SQL database because I'm not using doctrine at this point.

When running the app locally using GoogleAppEngineLauncher the following error is shown:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message '[WARNING 1549] failed to load external entity "file:////Users/gl/Repos/symfony-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd" (in n/a - line 0, column 0) [WARNING 3084] Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}import': Failed to locate a schema at location 'file:////Users/gl/Repos/symfony-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd'. Skipping the import. (in in_memory_buffer - line 8, column 0) [ERROR 1845] Element '{http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services}container': No matching global declaration available for the validation root. (in /Users/gl/Repos/symfony-standard/web/ - line 5, column 0)' in /Users/gl/Repos/symfony-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Util/XmlUtils.php:96 Stack trace: #0 /Users/gl/Repos/symfony-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Compone in /Users/gl/Repos/symfony-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php on line 234
```

When deploying to AppEngine the following error is shown before displaying the correct output which is the word 'homepage':

```
Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/swiftmailer-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/symfony/assetic-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/vendor/sensio/framework-extra-bundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Warning: opendir(/base/data/home/apps/e~sy-be/1.306537434952097690/src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /base/data/home/runtimes/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/Glob.php on line 124 Homepage.
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong..

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong. There is an issue in the PHP Runtime for the Google App Engine Launcher. Until it is fixed, the best way to get around the issue is to edit the `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader` class and make the function "validateSchema" return true.

**EDIT**

The above is referring to the problem you encountered locally (*"Failed to load external entity"*). To solve your second problem, I believe clearing the cache (using the `/clear_cache` URL specified [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/symfony-standard/blob/2.6.3/app.yaml#L9)) will fix the issue.

Comment: hI! Can you provide a link to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try running app/console server:run .. you shouldn't have any issues..

This is because Google Apps Engine has a read-only filesystem by "default".

Your file "stream"/"handler" is the prefix "gs://myfiles" rather than the traditional "file:///tmp/.

Symfony2 "standard" is broken when deployed with Google App Engine (Symfony needs to be able to create cache files, class maps, etc..).

I would recommend starting with a crash course at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/

This bundle looks like a decent shot to abstract away the filesystem: https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette .. I will be testing this shortly and will keep ya'll posted.

Comment: On another note.. *Abstraction is definitely the way to go* (we're gonna have to pay some technical debt here refactoring file_put&get_contents) .. BUT if it is a *crisis* then well, at least you can get half of the file writing and getting into a manageable design pattern... http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php should

Comment: The function throwing the local XML error is read-only, and since the AppEngine filesystem allows reads, this is not the cause. Also, thanks to Gaufrette's [inability to manage directories](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette/issues/115), this will not work with caching.